# Rebroadcast tf transforms with different frame_id on the fly

Tags: transform

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Due to some nomenclature difference between some packages and some simulator (especially considering tf transforms) I am looking for a nice way to change the frame_id and child_frame_id of some tf transforms and republish them directly, without having to touch the source code of any package. I thought about subscribing to /tf and then checking frame_id of each incoming transform. If it is the frame_id i need then create a new transform with the same translation and rotation data but with different frames and broadcast it.
For example I have a transform being published by STDR (new 2d simulator)

> map_static-> robot0

I want to rebroadcast it to

> odom->base_footprint

Is there something already implemented in ROS to do this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/193512/rebroadcast-tf-transforms-with-different-frame_id-on-the-fly/) by [Mehdi.](https://answers.ros.org/users/13601/mehdi./) on ROS Answers with karma: 3339 on 2014-09-25

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2014-09-25**:
You'll probably have to write that yourself, or reconfigure the frame names in the navigation stack.

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Here is my Code, which takes a transform A=>B and republishes it to B=>A_new. I used it to make markers, which appear as children of the camera, a parent of the camera.

Just change the values.

Cheers,

Rabe

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rospy
import tf

if __name__ == '__main__':
    rospy.init_node("transform_inverter")
    rospy.sleep(0.5)

    child_frame = rospy.get_param("~child_frame")
    parent_frame = rospy.get_param("~parent_frame")
    new_parent_name = rospy.get_param("~new_parent_frame")

    listener = tf.TransformListener()
    broadcaster = tf.TransformBroadcaster()
    rate = rospy.Rate(100)

    while not rospy.is_shutdown():
        try:
            listener.waitForTransform(parent_frame, child_frame, rospy.Time.now(), rospy.Duration(2.0))
            (trans, rot) = listener.lookupTransform(child_frame, parent_frame, rospy.Time(0))
            broadcaster.sendTransform(trans,rot, rospy.Time.now(), parent_frame, new_parent_name)
        except (tf.LookupException, tf.ConnectivityException, tf.ExtrapolationException, tf.Exception):
            rospy.loginfo("Couldn't find a transform")
            continue
```

---

Originally posted by [Rabe](https://answers.ros.org/users/15571/rabe/) with karma: 683 on 2014-09-26

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

Answer (score 1):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Node for this job, I have in daily use:
https://github.com/andreasBihlmaier/ahbros/blob/master/scripts/tf_alias_node.py

---

Originally posted by [andreasBihlmaier](https://answers.ros.org/users/13776/andreasbihlmaier/) with karma: 56 on 2014-10-01

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2